# MIME error in ui5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to delete multiple lines from the table. But I am getting a mime error.

Please help me to resolve it.

eg: [enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/openui5-table-json/831/edit/)

Thanks and Regards,
Vicky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit so it can be running in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wuweluyufulu/5/).

The service http://services.odata.org/V2/(S(2pxev2v2zqtidlzbqzhncots))/OData/OData.svc/Categories does not support batch request for DELETE. See the response body. If you want to do multiple deletion, you can send multiple DELETE question one by one using ODataModel.remove

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code/>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">
        Content is unexpected for the Delete operation.            
    </message>
</error>
```

Also For `submitBatch(fnSuccess?, fnError?, bAsync?)`, the document indicates:

**{function}    fnSuccess?**

- a callback function which is called when the batch request has been successfully sent. Note: **There might have errors occured in the single batch operations**. These errors can be accessed in the aErrorResponses parameter in the callback handler. The handler can have the following parameters: oData, oResponse and aErrorResponses.

You have to check the parameter `aErrorResponses` in the success function callback to see if there is any error occurred. See the following for batch delete and check error responses.

```js
var indices = oTable.getSelectedIndices();

if (indices.length == 0) {
    alert("Please Select a row to Delete");
    return;
} else {
    alert("selected " + indices);
    var batchChanges = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        var selectedRow = oTable.getRows()[i];
        var selectedId = selectedRow.getCells()[0].getValue();
        var selectedName = selectedRow.getCells()[1].getValue();
        var del = m.createBatchOperation(
            "Categories(" + selectedId + ")",
            "DELETE"
        );
        batchChanges.push(del);
    }

    m.addBatchChangeOperations(batchChanges);
    m.submitBatch(function(oData, oResponse, aErrorResponses) {
        if (aErrorResponses.length > 0) {
            alert(aErrorResponses[0].response.body);
        } else {
            m.refresh();
            m.clearBatch();
            alert("success");
        }
    }, function(err) {
        alert("error occured");
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Allen. Is there any example for batch delete.

Comment: Hi vignesh, see my updated answer and i just edit the code to enable mutli select for table and batch delete when select multiple rows to delete at http://jsbin.com/wuweluyufulu/5/.

Comment: Hi Allen. You have mentioned that the URL will not support Delete operation but by using the chrome Advanced REST client and postman, I can able to perform the delete operation.

Comment: Hi vignesh, I just checked for DELETE request for single entry. it seems to work. But with batch request for DELETE, the server responded with the mentioned not expected error.

Comment: Hi Allen. Now I understood the concept. But when I test your code, the multiple line batch delete throws the same error as i have mentioned before. It means whether the multiple line deletion in not possible with the odata? or multiple line deletion in not possible with the online odata service url's?

Comment: Hi vignesh, i don't know why the odata service does not support batch delete. i just update the code http://jsbin.com/mopuduhiride/1/edit by calling DELETE action single request multiple times to delete multiple rows.

Comment: Hi Allen. I came to know that Odata public URL is not allowed to perform multiple deletions. So what u have updated is correct.